# Filter by datetime and update dataframe based on other dataframe datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, filter

I just have started learning pandas, so I am only at the beginning of the road. :)

**The situation** :
I have two dataframes (df1 and df2).

df1 contains multiple sensor data of a machine. The sensors transmit data every minute. I set the index of df1 in datetime format (this is actually the date and time when the sensors sent the data). 
[image]

df2 contains the data of one production unit, meaning the unit id number (this is named 'Sarzs' in the dataframe) and the datetime when the process started and ended as well as the output quality of that particular production unit. The dataframe does not contain the data of the production unit related to that particular time (in the dataframe you can see that the column "Sarzs_no" is set to NaN at this stage). The starting and stopping dates and times of the production unit are stored in the "Start" and "Stop" columns and are in datetime format.
[image]

**The problem**:
I would like to iterate throught the rows of df1 and through the rows of df2 and check wether they are within (or between) the "Start" and "Stop" time of df2 and if this statement is true then udpdate the df1['Sarzs_no'] value with
the df2['Output'] value.

**The progress so far:**: 
So far I have wrote the code below:

```
for i in range (0, len(df2.index)):
    for j in range(0, len(df1.index)):
        print (df1.index)
```

and I have two questions basically:

1. How to actually write the filtering code and do the update?
2. Isn't there (it should be, I guess) a better way to make the filtering then iterating through all the rows in both dataframes, which it seems very time consuming therefore inefficient to me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**. This means no links/images, just text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dataframes containing timestamps as datetime object you could use something like the following :

```
#Loop over the dataframe containing start and end timestamps
for index,row in df2.iterrows():
    #Create a boolean mask to filter data
    mask = (df1.index > row['Start']) & (df1.index < row['Stop']) 
    df1.loc[mask,'Sarzs_no'] = row['Output']
```

This will make the rows that match the condition of the mask have the Output label of the row, for each rows of your dataframe containing start & end timestamps

The [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) function return the indexes of the rows that match the conditions and the [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) function create an iterator that move through your dataframe row by row

**EDIT**

As you have a datetime index, you can just use :

```
df1[row['Start']:row['Stop']]
```

instead of .loc() to get the rows you need to update